# Blender 2.90.1 Keying Node doesn't seem to work. Am I missing a switch somewhere, or does keying need to be added to the clip like a mask?

Tags: compositing-nodes, chromakey

The Keying Node doesn't seem to work. Am I overlooking a switch somewhere, or does keying need to be "added" to the clip, as masking does, in order for it to render? Here is my compositor node set up.
[image: the compositor set up for my test clip]

It is set up according to various tutorials that I found, but nothing doing. Thanks.

here is the blend file:
[image]

Comment: Why are you using alpha over to overlay the keyed image over the original? Get rid of the alpha over node.

Comment: I've tried without it too, and no joy. I'd like to send the blender up here as an attachment too

Comment: I edited the original post with the blend file

Answer (score 0):

I FINALLY got to the bottom of it. There was a video loaded in the sequencer that was rendering INSTEAD of what was set up in the compositor. Once I deleted the clip from the sequencer, all was good. Hope this helps!

Comment: "for whatever reason" is no reason at all. Harley an answer. Did you press F12 to refresh the compositor's data?

Comment: I had already tried his solution before. The screen I had made was in the middle of everything I tried. Nothing was working.

Didn't know I had to refresh any data. As a last resort, I pulled the video out, and reloaded it. When I reloaded the video, after purging all the empties, it worked. Nothing else made it happen. That is why I didn't give him the answer.

Comment: I FINALLY got to the bottom of it. There was a video loaded in the sequencer that was rendering INSTEAD of what was set up in the compositor. Once I deleted the clip from the sequencer, all was good. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the help, no-can-do